# One To Many Polymorphic relationship - Call to undefined method getConnectionName()

Tags: laravel, eloquent, polymorphic-associations, laravel-9

I have followed the documentation very closely but something isn't working 
https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-polymorphic-relations

I am trying to add permissions into my code which will give a User access to a File or a Folder. I understand this needs a one-to-many polymorphic relationship as each Permission has one permissionable, while each File or Folder might have many permissions.
`$table->morphs('permissionable');` in a migration adds the `permissionable_type`(string) and `permissionable_id`(integer) columns to the permissions table
[image: phpMyAdmin Screenshot]

The Permission model has been created with the relevant fillable columns and the permissionable method containing a morphTo():

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

use App\Models\File;

class Permission extends Model
{
    use HasFactory, SoftDeletes;
    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id',
        'permissionable_type',
        'permissionable_id',
        'privilege',
    ];
    /**
     * Get the parent object (file or folder).
     */
    public function permissionable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}
```

The Folder and File models have both had the following methods added:

```
    public function permissions()
    {
        return $this->morphMany(Permission::class, 'permissionable');
    }
```

A Permission is going to be created which will share a File with a User
[image: File]
[image: Permission]
And then the Permission is found and it's permissionable is requested
`dd(Permission::find(1)->permissionable);`

Except this is where the area happens:
[image]

I have tried to follow the documentation religiously and all the answers I see online just say to check namespace or ensure that all Models have an `extends Model` which I have already done.
Let me know if there is any more information I need to provide, thanks in advance.

Comment: My guess is that somewhere you have imported  Illuminate\Support\Facades\File instead of App\Models\File

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Noah and Erik for their answers. You both helped me find the solution which was on the following site.
https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/polymorphic-relations-gives-class-staff-not-found 
The types need to include the paths in the database 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

i think you just changes model File class name, it's ok.
because this model's name conflict with Facades File class name